# Arduino/AVR: Is it safe to interrupt Serial/I2C communications

Tags: arduino, avr, i2c, atmel

I want to do some interrupt-driven signal processing on an Atmega328, which might not have enough SRAM (2K) to store the data of an entire run. This means I'll have to write part of the buffer to external memory while still gathering data.

My question is whether it is safe to have serial writes or I2C communications (e.g. to an SD card) while still triggering interrupts. I think serial communications themselves are interrupt driven so this might become an issue. Is this true? How about I2C? If both are likely to cause problems, what would be the recommended way (if any) to flush a buffer while still gathering data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a common scenario and really depends on how much processing time you require exactly for each task and how tight your timing restrictions are regarding the device communication.

Thinks you should review/consider:

- You have to be able to write data faster to the external RAM than it is acquired -> How fast do you gather data?
- See that you spent as little time as possible in your interrupt handlers
- Have an eye on interrupt starvation. Priority can cause ISR A not to be executed if ISR B triggers more frequently that AND has higher priority. Adjust execution interval if possible.
- Check what serial data has to be sent in sequence or in short succession to honor timing requirements. You may have to pause/delay other processing for a short time.

Comment: Thanks very much :-) I did some calculations and I think the 2K of memory might just be enough. Flushing the buffer could therefore be done after recording the data. Nevertheless, these tips will come in very handy if want to implement a backup mechanism, which I probably will... Thanks again!